# Opening a Google staticmap from Java Swing application

Tags: java, maps, desktop

I need to open a browser from my Java Swing application with a URL pointing to a staticmap from Google.

I use the 1.6 Desktop class to open the browser, but I am getting the following error:

> Internet Explorer cannot download staticmap from mpas.google.com. 
>   Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site.  The
>   requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.  Please try
>   again later.

However, when I open Internet Explorer and paste the URL it works fine.

Why is Internet Explorer not working?  This is the URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=6&size=400x400&markers=color:green%7Clabel:1%7C30.652934,-95.575821&sensor=false

Here is the code snipplet where I open the URL:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
if (!desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
    System.out.println("Desktop does not support browse mode.");
} else {
    try {
        URI uri = new URI("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=6&size=400x400&markers=color:green%7Clabel:1%7C40.837375,-85.646872&sensor=false");
        desktop.browse(uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe post the code snippet where you try to open the URL...

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I changed the format of the image. Google maps download as default a png image. 
Changing to gif (parameter &format=gif) solved my problem.